# Angular 4 IIS routing issue

Tags: angular, iis-7.5, angular2-routing

I have implemented a Angular 4 application and ready for deployment to IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 so just simplify things I just created a new Angular 4 project using Angular CLI and build it with ng build --prod.  Then Added a new Web Site in IIS named AngularApp and map to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\AngularApp.   I copied over all the files under dist.  I also added the URL rewrite to web.config.  When I go to URL http://localhost/AngularApp, I see the Loading... but app works! never show.  I know there are some similar issues already raised but I follow everything I find online by changing  `<base href="/"/>` to `<base href="/AngularApp/"/>` and the URL rewrite but doesn't seem to find a solution. Angular code is directly from Angular CLI without modification. Not sure what I am missing here...

Below is the rewrite

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="angularjs routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem.  Since our Server only has IE installed, IE was launched. After opening up the developer tool, I see that I get an Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference error.  I had to remove the commented out code in pollyfills.ts to support IE11.  After that then I do see the app works!